# how to union two collection in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (self:Person {id:"13619240353"})-[r1]-(N1)-[r2]-(N2) 
where self<>N2  return collect(N1),collect(N2),
self,collect(r2),collect(distinct r1)
```

I want to merge collect(N1) and collect(N2) into one collection and then return ,how can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily combine 2 lists using the `+` operator, as in:

```
MATCH (self:Person {id:"13619240353"})-[r1]-(N1)-[r2]-(N2) 
WHERE self <> N2
RETURN
  collect(N1) + collect(N2),
  self, collect(r2), collect(distinct r1)
```